# Почему не выводится изображение на canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas">
 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  const canv = document.querySelector('#canvas')
  const context = canv.getContext('2d')
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = "../img/image/main.png"
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
 </script>

</html>
```

Самое интересное, что когда я закомментировал этот код и вставлял каждую команду в консоли, то всё нормально работает, а через код оно вообще не работает. Даже в консоли ничего не выводится.

Comment: Попробуйте тег script перенести перед закрывающимся тегом body.

Comment: `context.drawImage()` поместите в `image.onload`. К тому моменту как загрузится изображение и появятся данные для для использования, код уже не выполняется.

Comment: Ох ты ж ёмаё! @Leonid, большое тебе спасибо! Твой совет мне действительно помог и изображение успешно вывелось на холст.

Comment: Тогда изучите проблему и сами дайте ответ)) Будет полезно. То есть, загрузка данных проходит асинхронно и с помощью `.onload` мы вешаем событие на полную загрузку данных, а затем используем их.

Comment: @Leonid я всегда прежде чем спрашивать, пытаюсь сам найти ответ. Конкретно в этом случае я допустил достаточно тупую ошибку и почему-то сразу не догадался, что надо дождаться самой загрузки изображения. В любом случае, ещё раз спасибо) Такого не допущу никогда больше)

Comment: @Anisimov, просто вопрос без ответа теперь будет. Кроме вас, думаю, никому уже не интересно отвечать - интриги нет)) Ответьте, плюсиков накидаем хоть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодаря ценной (для меня подсказке :-) от ***@Leonid'a*** попробовал сделать загрузку сразу трех изображений вместо одного.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var loaded = 0;
var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = new Image();
var img3 = new Image();

img1.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Os1.jpg";
img2.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/z57xC.jpg";
img3.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPcfs.jpg";

img1.onload = drawImages;
img2.onload = drawImages;
img3.onload = drawImages;

function drawImages() {
  loaded += 1;

  if (loaded === 3) {
    context.drawImage(img1, 10, 100, 300, 300);
    context.drawImage(img2, 300, 100, 300, 300);
    context.drawImage(img3, 600, 100, 350, 300);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: эммм... это решение не работает. ты  сразу имеешь массив с тремя элементами, а значит `loaded.length == 3` сразу `true` и картинки выводятся только за счет первого отступа в 400мс

Comment: [.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - возвращает количество элементов в массиве после добавления. Соответственно вот такие строки `img1.onload = loaded.push('img1');` не имеют смысла.

Comment: (¬‿¬) ты мог бы задать вопрос с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода], правда тут не рабочий код и можно без нее задавать :)

Comment: во-первых, тебе не нужен массив: ты не учитываешь ни очередность, ни имена файлов. Поэтому достаточно просто счетчика. Во-вторых, в обработчиках `onload` достаточно изменять счетчик загруженных и в случае если загрузились все - выполнять отрисовку. В этом случае блок с setInterval вообще не нужен

Comment: @Grundy будь так добр. Сделай ответ, я знаю, что у тебя получится быстро и хорошо. Слова ведь понимаются по разному, а твой код был бы очень полезен и нагляден. Это не вызов, а просьба о помощи

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Твой ответ очень ценный и полезный для меня.